# Padding on Y-axis [AChart engine]

Tags: android, android-view, achartengine

I am working on bar graphs with AChart engine. Here is the code snippet.

```
XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();             
renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
renderer.setChartValuesSpacing((float) 5.5d);
renderer.setLineWidth((float) 10.5d);

XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();            
mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);    
mRenderer.setShowLegend(true);
mRenderer.setShowGridX(true);      
mRenderer.setShowGridY(true);              
mRenderer.setBarSpacing(.5);   
mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
mRenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
mRenderer.setXAxisMax(5);
mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(20f);
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(1,"Income");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(2,"Saving");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(3,"Expenditure");
mRenderer.addXTextLabel(4,"NetIncome");
mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
```

And here is what that shows up.

[image]

See **Y axis labels** are over the axis. In order to get over it, I set the padding.

```
mRenderer.setYLabelsPadding(20f);
```

However, the result is not what I expected.

[image]

**Y axis** values have gone past the screen. How could I align labels relative to Y-axis with proper padding? Is there anything I am lacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to define the size of your left margin:

```
mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] {0, 50, 0, 0});
```

The values in the array are top, left, bottom, right.

Answer (score -1):

I solved it like this:

```
int yMax=xySeriesIdle.getMaxY();
renderer.setYAxisMax(yMax+yMax/5d);
```

which gives 1/5 of extra space for the y-values.